# DateTime format for c#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, format

I'm writing some dates to sql from a text file. In text file date format like `10.01.2013`(dd.mm.yyyy) but when i write it on sql it seems `2013-01-10 what should to add it as 10.01.2013

Here is my code:

```
en.LogDateTime = DateTime.Parse(myDateString);
```

Comment: Is `10.01.2013` supposed to be January 10th or October 1st?

Comment: i think whatever DB is showing it you is correct

Comment: What do you mean "when I write it on SQL". If you're looking at it in a SQL client, it's important to remember that's just how sql outputs the date (stored as a number), not how it is actually stored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method to specify exactly what format your input string should be

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("10.01.2013", "MM.dd.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTimeFormatInfo dateformat= new DateTimeFormatInfo();
dateformat.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
dateformat.DateSeparator = ".";
DateTime objDate = Convert.ToDateTime(strDate, dateformat);
```

if you want to specify the format while inserting the data into table you can use following sql query:

```
dateformat dmy;
insert into mytable values(mydatetime);
```

Comment: i'm using LLBLGEN so i think i cant use sql queries